# How would I connect 12 MG996R servo motors to a 4.8 volt four AA power supply via GPIO pins common between all parts?

Tags: power-supply, servo

The servo motors have GPIO wires for data, ground, and voltage.  I have a power supply that, similarly to the servo motors, has a GPIO pinout with ground and voltage. The problem I'm running into is connecting ALL the servo motors to the power supply simultaneously.  The data wires are handled on the microcontroller assembly.

Comment: What does the GPIO do? Do you want all the servo motors to act identically? Or do you want to control each individually? If the latter, do you have 12 separate GPIO's available?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where's the problem with connecting twelve wires to the battery positive terminal and twelve wires to the battery negative?

Comment: @DavideAndrea the microcontroller is an esp32-wroom devkit, I intend to use espruino to run the servos.  However, supplying power to the servos is proving to be an issue.  Also yes the esp32 board does have 12 separate open gpio pins, it just cant handle the proper voltage so it needs a standalone power supply.

Comment: @JRE I have two gpio wires, one positive and one negative, coming from my 4 AA power supply, and I have 24 positive and negative wires overall coming from my mg996r servo motors that would need to connect to said positive and negative ends.  Since I don't want to clip off the gpio pins id need some sort of splitter for the power supply.  Right?

Comment: (I'm still fond of miniature lever clamps.)

Comment: @K-Fehrb. Would you mind posting or linking to what you are calling "GPIO pins?"  I have a feeling you are using that term differently than what most people expect.

Comment: "The esp32 board  it just cant handle the proper voltage so it needs a standalone power supply.". So? You know the solution. Why are you asking us if you already know?

Comment: You'd better clarify what the _actual_ issue is in the next few minutes, or someone will close your question for being unclear.

Comment: I can't comprehend HOW to connect the pins to the power supply, I have 2 wires supplying and 24 wires consuming, also let me get an image real fast to show what I mean cause I also think the seller is simply not defining them properly.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/REXQualis-120pcs-Breadboard-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B072L1XMJR/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=raspberry+pi+jumper+wires&qid=1678212042&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyRU5FUlA3M1JGOUozJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMjM5MzI2MThYNVJXUFBYSUtZMSZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNjU2MzA0MjVLREdCSVlYUTZXQiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=, Jumper cables that have the same headers, I've just been calling them gpio pins, likely incorrectly.  @JRE